# Python/Django: Getting random articles from huge table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a huge table in my database (MySQL)with millions of data. I need to populate 10 random data and show it on the UI. What would be a good approach considering performance?

I was thinking about creating MySQL View to populate 10 random rows and read it from UI. Or is there any other efficient way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all (it's my proper opinion) i'm against using raw SQL when we are already working with a hight level framework like Django unless we don't find what we are looking for in the framework (Django) , so i will rather use Django for this matter:

remark this approach it's only working if you have set auto increment to you PK and of course if you data is consistent (you don't remove record from the table so that you can be sure that all ids are auto incremented)

```
 import random

 # Getting the number of rows in the table it's equivalent to do SELECT COUNT(*).
 count_record = Table.objects.count() 

 # Choose 10 (at most) number from the list of all ids. 
 random_pks = random.sample(range(1, count_record) , min(count_record, 10))

 random_list = Table.objects.filter(pk__in=random_pks)
```

if the condition sited before are not satisfied i think you can do it with an raw SQL query like this:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10""")

table.objects.raw(query)
```

about performance i think you have to timeit, Hope this will help.

Comment: I thought of this approach, too. However, it is not guaranteed that all ids between 1 and count_record exist (some may have been deleted). So, to make it work you need to try: and except DoesNotExist until you have 10, which is slightly more complicated and may be expensive.

Comment: @tz : agree that why i put the condition that should be satisfied before using the first way , and i don't think the __try except__ will work there either because if the condition are not satisfied and knowing that __random.sample__ is getting rand __from 1 to count__ and assuming that __id of the last record == count__ so if some data have been removed the __count != last_id__ so the __random.sample__ will not give us correct data it will forget some record

Comment: It seems ORDER BY RAND() is not a good idea because it calculates a random number for each row: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql

Comment: Also, note that 10 might not be smaller than table.count() in which case random.sample will not work.

Comment: @Patrick: Good catch, i edited my answer to reflect this case

Answer (score 3):

This may be expensive and slow, but:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('?')[:10]
```

The main advantages being clarity and that it is not raw SQL.